# What does the digest and signature fields correspond to in the WS-Security x509 token profile?

Tags: soap, signature, ws-security, x509

an x509 cert has:
a) the info, 
b) the public key, 
c) a signed value made from hashing (a)+(b), and then encrypted using the private key

The x509 token profile includes the digestValue and signatureValue elements, shown in this example:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfhws/wsSecurity/dfhws_soapmsg_signed.htm

My question is, is the value of signatureValue the same as c)? And is digestValue the hash of a)+b)? If so, why is there a redundancy? Or am I not understanding something? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DigestValue and SignatureValue tags are properties of the document, not of the certificate. DigestValue is a value of the digest calculated over the signed nodes, and SignatureValue is the signature of the digest, made using the key, information about which (key) is specified in KeyInfo.

You need to refer to [XMLDSig standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As some followup questions:
1. Is the private key used for the document signature going to be the same as private key used for the x509 signature? (why would they be different?) 
2. What is specifically getting hashed to get the digest value? Just the value of the base-64 encoded x509 certificate? 

Sorry if these questions are kind of stupid/obvious; I'm clearly not a security expert.

Comment: 1. The private key is part of the certificate. It is used to sign the document (XML data in your case). Certificate is usually signed using the private key of CA certificate (also called signer certificate). There exists self-signed certificates, where certificate's private key is used to sign certificate public part, but they can't be trusted (in most cases) and so are not widely used in public environments.

Comment: 2. It's the *XML data* that is hashed, not certificate.

Comment: I suggest that you read one of the books mentioned here (https://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=1842) to get acquainted with PKI and certificates.